# XSLT remove spaces from phone number

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to format a string to remove spaces from a phone number and am having trouble.  The code I am using is:

```
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="EmployeeCellPhone != ''">
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(EmployeeCellPhone, ' ',' ')"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(EmployeeHomePhone, ' ',' ')"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
```

However, it does not work.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?  The current output looks like this: 123 456 7890 and I need the results to look like: 1234567890

Comment: You need to remove the space in the third arg...`translate(EmployeeHomePhone,' ','')`

Comment: that worked, thanks @DanielHaley

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are replacing a space with a space.
I also don't think you need a condition if you always want to replace the spaces.

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(EmployeeCellPhone, ' ', '')"/>
```

See it working here : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/naZYrpC